# Trouble converting display date back to date format for update

Tags: php, mysql, date-conversion

A date stored in the database as DATE format with a value of

```
2017-04-06
```

Able to properly convert for display as follows so that the user can change it (if necessary):

```
$date_order = date("m/d/y", strtotime($data['date_order']));
```

This is properly displayed as

```
04/06/17
```

Trying to convert back to Date format (Y-m-d) when doing an update to the database using the following:

```
$date_ship = date('Y-m-d',$_POST['date_ship']);
```

Unfortunately, it converts to the following value:

```
1970-01-01
```

error Log = "A non well formed numeric value encountered".

Comment: @Fred - for the 'happy path test' I have not changed the value, just trying to convert back to date format what is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert string into timestamp, using `strtotime()` function.

```
$date_ship = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['date_ship']));
```

[Alex Howansky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43375407/7804082) offers more bulletproof solution, so you could use it as well.

```
$date_ship = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/y', $_POST['date_ship'])->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have a string like "04/06/17" there's no definitive way to tell if 04 is the day or the month. You can use the [`createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) method to specify explicitly what you want.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/y', '04/06/17');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```